# Binding IsEnabled property to items.count

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, isenabled

I have the following tree view template :

```
<TreeView x:Name="counterTree" ItemsSource="{Binding CounterCheckBoxList}" x:FieldModifier="private">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Name="counterTreePanel">
                <CheckBox Background="LightBlue" 
                         IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" Checked="CounterTreeCheckBoxChecked" Unchecked="CounterTreeCheckBoxUnchecked"
                                                  VerticalAlignment="Center" Tag="{Binding Id}" />

                <Label Content="{Binding Name }" 
                       Tag="{Binding ParentId}"
                       Name="counterLabel" 
                       Padding="1,1,1,1" />
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>

    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
            <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="False" />
            <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.AcceptsReturn" Value="True" />
        </Style>
   </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
</TreeView>
```

The `ItemsSource` of the `TreeView` is `List<CounterCheckBox>`.

CounterCheckBox class has a property as : public List Children.

My requirement was that if this list is empty the 'CheckBox' should not be visible and it there are Children the Checkbox should be visible.How do I bind the count of the list to the Visiblity property of the Checkbox.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a [IValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).